# How to subtract two column values , one from a table and other from the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
select C_Id , CD.Sd_Id, BU_Id ,CB.SpendPriority ,BudgetAmount ServiceBudgetAmount
from ContractBudget CB
    JOIN ContractDetail CD ON CB.Id = CD.CB_Id
    WHERE CB.C_Id =367 AND CD.Sd_Id = 2239
```

which returns me the following record.

```
C_Id    Sd_Id   BU_Id   SpendPriority   ServiceBudgetAmount
367 2239    220 Normal  100000.00
```

and i also have a stored proc

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PaymentServiceDetailBusinessUnitAllocation]
        @MRRId = 592,
        @SDId = 2239

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

which returns me the following result

```
BusinessUnit    E1Description   Fund    SpendPriority   ServiceType TotalPaymentAmount
12341232    created for Ram-MH1 CF  Normal  MH  220.00
```

can any one help me how to caluclate the values
servicebudgetamount - totalpaymentamount

i need result as

```
availableamount= 99780
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create/declare temp table with columns same to sp output (names/datatypes). Then do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table
EXEC your_stored_proc...
```

Then you can compare what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [saclar valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499(v=sql.105).aspx), not a stored procedure and it would be something like this

```
declare @ServiceBudgetAmount int
declare @TotalPaymentAmount int

select  @ServiceBudgetAmount = BudgetAmount
    from ContractBudget CB
    JOIN ContractDetail CD ON CB.Id = CD.CB_Id
    WHERE CB.C_Id =367 AND CD.Sd_Id = 2239

    set @TotalPaymentAmount = YourNewFunction ( 592, 2239);

    select @ServiceBudgetAmount - @TotalPaymentAmount  as Result
```